# Unzipping multiple zip files in a directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, gzip

I need to unzip multiple files within a directory and convert them to a csv file.
The files are numbered in order within the file, 1.gz, 2.gz, 3.gz etc

Can this be done within a single script or do I have to do it manually?

edit: current code is

```
 #! /usr/local/bin/python

import gzip
import csv
import os

f = gzip.open('1.gz', 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
filename = '1.txt'
target = open ('1.txt', 'w')
target.write(file_content)
target.close()
filename = '1.csv'
txt_file = '1.txt'
csv_file = '1.csv'
in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
dirname = '/home/user/Desktop'
filename = "1.txt"
pathname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
if pathname.startswith(dirname):
os.remove(pathname)
f.close()
```

Current plan is to do a count for the total number of .gz files per directory and use a loop for each file to unzip and print the txt/csv out.

Is it feasible or is there a better way to this?

Also, is python similar to perl in which the double quotes interpretes the string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Not everyone is willing to do *their work* for *them* :)

Comment: I would upload code as fast as possible, but currently the codes are in my school's lab. I'll produce the codes when I have access to it for more information!

Comment: You need to unzip **multiple** files and conver them to **a** single text file? Or you need to unzip multiple files and convert each one to the corresponding text file?

Comment: I need to convert each one to their corresponding text file.

Answer (score 0):

You hardly need Python for this :)

But you **can** do this in a single Python script. You'll need to use:

- os
- os.path (*possibly*)
- gzip
- glob (*will get your a nice glob listing of files. e.g: `glob("*.gz")`*)

Have a read up on these modules over at https://docs.python.org/ and have a go! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, just needed a direction to work towards! :)

Comment: No problems. Starting at the docs is always a good starting place!